# How does Denver/Carmel handle optimization cache overflow

Tags: hardware, nvidia

**Prologue**

I am not sure whether I should ask this question on Stackoverflow or Super User or even another stack exchange site, so please direct me if there is a more suitable place.

**Main Body**

I read the [IEEE paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7045419&tag=1) by Nvidia introducing Denver and found that about optimization cache management, only the part quoted below is relevant.

> Optimization cache management uses a mark-and-sweep algorithm to manage the available optimization execution memory.

However, I would like to know if the optimization cache is full, but the dynamic code optimizer (DCO) decides to optimize some more ARM instructions into native micro-ops, what will happen?

I can think of three possible implementations, but I am not sure which one is true.

1. Keep using the hardware decoder to deal with newly-encountered ARM instructions until the optimization cache has enough space.
2. Record some statistics to decide whether a optimized block of code needs to be replaced.
3. Simply flush the optimization cache.

Google yields no results, and I appreciate any references I may have overlooked.